# Elasticsearch aggregation tophits - scaling

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

PS: This query works fine for a smaller dataset. The problem starts happening with huge dataset. So trying to see what are the other scale options that can be used.

What is the max size of # of documents you could have if you need to use aggregation terms + top_hits for an elasticsearch query given you have as much resources needed in terms of CPU, memory, etc?
I have a dataset with more than a million documents.

I have a dataset with more than a million documents. When the db is  populated with approx more than 60K documents, it starts hitting readTimeout error from Elastic. My query has aggregation terms + top_hits because i need to get the list of unique documents across the entire dateset.
I tried removing top_hits from the query and it works fine but since i need to access the _source for each of these unique documents, i do not know of any other way to get that than top_hits.

ES query:

```
query = {
            "size": 0,
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [],
                    "filter": {
                        "range": {
                            "time": {
                                "lte": timestamp,
                                "format": "date_optional_time"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by": {
                    "terms": {
                        "size" : 450000,
                        "field": group_by_field
                        },
                    "aggs": {
                        "resource": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "from": 0,
                                "size": 1,
                                "sort" : {
                                    "time" : "desc"
                                },
                                "_source": {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 384, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 380, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1321, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 296, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 257, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 298, in recv_into
    raise timeout('The read operation timed out')
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 172, in perform_request
    response = self.pool.urlopen(method, url, body, retries=Retry(False), headers=request_headers, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 343, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=read_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 306, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self, url, "Read timed out. (read timeout=%s)" % timeout_value)
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elasticsearch.service.apic.local', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)
ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elasticsearch.service.apic.local', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=60))
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Comment: You set agg size to 450k. When you have 60k documents you possibly require ES to return 60k results (depending on cardinality of group_by_field). That's a huge dataset to return in single response and ES can't respond in time (so you receive timeout or maybe even outOfMemory exception).

Comment: @Bernard - the range of documents in my usecase can go upto 1 million. What I mentioned above is the observation when it reaches stage of 60K, it starts giving timeout. Are you saying i should have approx 1 million records and then test the above query ? i cannot change the size on runtime based on records. it has to be an approximation of how many max documents i could have. Hope the ask is clear.

Comment: I'm saying that you're trying to pull too much data in **single** request. To be precise you're fetching 60k buckets and that's just too much data to "chew up" at once and your client or ES just crashes. 
You can try [composite aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) which can scroll results or with [terms partitions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_partitions) which split results to smaller chunks